# VBA Cubevalue referencing

Tags: vba, excel

I am quite new to VBA and I have problem with inserting Cubevalue formula.

I can insert formula like this.

```
Formula = "=CUBEVALUE(""ThisWorkbookDataModel"",""[Measures].[MTD]"",""[DataAll_Qe].[Attribute].&[""&R19C&""]"",""[MaterialMatrix_Qe].[Material].&[""&RC3&""]"",""[CalendarMatrix_Qe].[TIP].&[""&R20C&""]"",Slicer_Month,Slicer_Subcategory)"
```

What I want is that instead of inserting member &[""&R19C&""]" it is dynamic and it inserts Frow(defined variable for first row)minus one. So if I change first row to 25 it inserts &[""&R24C&""]".

Hope you can help me. The whole purpose is to copy than this value formula from First row/First column to Last row/Last Column.

There are be many rows and 4 columns. 
I have managed to make formula, only problem is that it is static with referenced member expressions.

Regards,

Eagle